# Get and use the value from foreign key field without any conversions (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I tried to **get the value from the foreign key field "tax" in "priceWithTax()"**, then finally, I could get the value with this code below:

```py
taxObject = self.tax
```

This is the full code:

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models
from decimal import Decimal

class Tax(models.Model):
    tax = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3, 
        decimal_places=0,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ],
    )

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    TAX_ID = 1
    tax = models.ForeignKey(
        Tax,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        default=TAX_ID,
    )

    @property
    def priceWithTax(self):
        # Here
        taxObject = self.tax
        tax = Decimal(str(taxObject))

        return round(self.price * ((tax + 100) / 100), 2)
```

But to use the value, I needed to convert it to **"String" type** first and then **"Decimal type"** next which became a little bit long code as shown below:

```py
taxObject = self.tax
tax = Decimal(str(taxObject)) # Here
```

So, are there any ways to use **the value from the foreign key field "tax" in "priceWithTax()"** without any conversions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **the value from the foreign key field "tax" in "priceWithTax()" without any conversions**.

So, replace this code:

```py
taxObject = self.tax
tax = Decimal(str(taxObject))
```

With this code:

```py
tax = self.tax.tax
```

This is the full code:

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models
from decimal import Decimal

class Tax(models.Model):
    tax = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3, 
        decimal_places=0,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ],
    )

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    TAX_ID = 1
    tax = models.ForeignKey(
        Tax,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        default=TAX_ID,
    )

    @property
    def priceWithTax(self):
        # Here
        tax = self.tax.tax        
        return round(self.price * ((tax + 100) / 100), 2)
```